# Suspicious warning C4238: nonstandard extension used: class rvalue used as lvalue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, c++20, move-semantics, stdstring

In this simple C++20 program

```cxx
#include <string>

std::string asString( std::u8string && s ) 
{ 
    return reinterpret_cast<std::string &&>( std::move( s ) ); // VS warning here
}

int main()
{
    auto s = asString( std::u8string( u8"a" ) );
}
```

I get a warning from Visual Studio 2019 16.10.0 in `stdcpplatest` mode:

```
warning C4238: nonstandard extension used: class rvalue used as lvalue
```

But the very same program compiles fine in gcc 11 and clang 12 with the options `-std=c++20 -Wall`, without any warnings.
Visual Studio warning disappears if one removes `std::move`. But I do not see how it is related to the warning, please explain.

Comment: Why don't you just do `return std::string(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(s.data()), s.size());`? The code you wrote accesses a `std::u8string` as if it were a `std::string`, which is UB. You *have* to copy the characters to the new string if you want to convert it.

Comment: Since char and char8_t have the same size, the internal representation of std::string and std::u8string will be the same. Your version may be safer in theory but it introduces an extra copy, which I would like to avoid. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: "*Since char and char8_t have the same size, the internal representation of std::string and std::u8string will be the same.*" Irrelevant. They are two distinct types, so accessing an object of one type through a reference of an unrelated type is UB by a violation of the strict aliasing rule. Also, a standard library implementation could have used a specialization for `std::string` that has a different representation for some reason from that of `std::u8string`. A copy is the only *legal* way to convert strings.

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks. Still it is intersecting why only VS issues some warning here, and that warning disappears after removing of std::move.

Comment: @Fedor: What extra copy?  The “temporary”, the return value, and `main::s` are all the same object since C++17 (and often before).

Comment: The suggestion was to make a copy of argument in asString() function