# Error in reinterpret_cast from and to rvalue reference

Tags: c++, visual-c++, rvalue-reference, reinterpret-cast

The following code

```cpp
int i;
reinterpret_cast<int &&>( std::move( i ) );
```

in Visual Studio 2022 results in

```
error C2102: '&' requires l-value
```

GCC an Clang do not see anything wrong with the code, online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/zeoEx864c

Since there is no `&` in the code at all and the type of `std::move( i )` is already `int &&`, is it just a bug in MSVC?

Comment: I'm more interested in the actual problem you're trying to solve with the `reinterpret_cast`. Why do you need to use it? What is the underlying problem that's supposed to solve? This has the smell of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that being said, it's still interesting to see the disagreement between compilers.

Comment: Seems that MSVC has not implemented [DR 1268](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1268.html). However, returning the result of the cast from the function in the compiler explorer link is UB because `i` has indeterminate value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thanks for your comment. Indeed the question seems useless. But actually it is a simplification of the code from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67749466/suspicious-warning-c4238-nonstandard-extension-used-class-rvalue-used-as-lvalu), which is from a real codebase. Surprisingly after simplification a warning became an error.